# How to dynamically show hide formik form field?

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I have a form written in Formik. I would like to disable the sub-category when the category is not picked. The sub-category should only open when the category is selected else it is disabled to be selected by the user. Please let me know how this would be possible. Thank you so much in advance. Please see the sample code below:

```
        const categoriesList = uniqueCategory.map((option) => ({
            label: option.category,
        }));

        const subcategoriesList = uniqueSubCategory.map((option) => ({
            label: option.sub_category,
        }));

        return (
        <div className='container'>
                <Formik
                    validateOnChange={true}
                    // form fields
                    initialValues={{
                        category: "",
                        sub_category: "",
                    }}
                    validationSchema={validationSchema}
                    onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
                        setSubmitting(true);
                        try {
                            const body = {
                                category: selectedCategories.label,
                                sub_category: selectedSubCategories.label,
                            };
                            console.log(body);
                            const response = fetch(
                                "http://" + hosted + ":5000/createpart",
                                {
                                    method: "POST",
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    },
                                    body: JSON.stringify(body),
                                }
                            )
                                .then((response) => {
                                    // response.json();  
                                })
                                .then(() => {
                                    setSubmitting(false);
                                    resetForm();
                                })
                                .then(() => {
                                    console.log("Success");
                                    setOpen(true);
                                })
                                .catch((error) => {
                                    console.error("Error:", error);
                                    alert("Failed to submit... ");
                                });
                        } catch (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    }}
                >
                    {({
                        values,
                        errors,
                        touched,
                        handleChange,
                        handleBlur,
                        handleSubmit,
                        isSubmitting,
                    }) => (
                            <div className='container'>
                                <Snackbar open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
                                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <Row style={formStyle}>
                                        <Col md={6}>
                                            <VirtSelect
                                                placeholder='Category'
                                                name='category'
                                                styles={reactSelectStyles998}
                                                options={categoriesList}
                                                value={selectedCategories}
                                                onChange={handleChangeSelectCategories}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col md={6}>
                                            <VirtSelect
                                                placeholder='Sub-Category'
                                                name='sub_category'
                                                styles={reactSelectStyles998}
                                                options={subcategoriesList}
                                                value={selectedSubCategories}
                                                onChange={handleChangeSelectSubCategories}
                                            />
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </Form>
                            </div>
                        )}
                </Formik>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: `disabled={!values.category}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition check before you render sub category.

```
values.category && (
    <Col md={6}><VirtSelect placeholder='Sub-Category' name='sub_category' styles={reactSelectStyles998} options={subcategoriesList} value={selectedSubCategories} onChange={handleChangeSelectSubCategories}/></Col>)
```

Comment: This partially works. The initial value of the category is "" so it won't display the subcategory but as soon as the user selects a category I want the subcategory to display which it is not doing.  My category is editable using handlechange. {values.category !== "" && (
          <Col md={6}><VirtSelect placeholder='Sub-Category' name='sub_category' styles={reactSelectStyles998} options={subcategoriesList} value={selectedSubCategories} onChange={handleChangeSelectSubCategories} /></Col>)}